# Button fill div height using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my div col-md-9 to have a height the same as the content in my first div col-md-3's contents.

I also want my div col-md-9's button inside to be the same height as the col-md-3's content.

I'd like the text on the button to fill the button also.

How do I accomplish this?

```
<div class="row" style="height:300px;">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="@(Url.Content("~/ProjectTimer/LITL.DesktopTimer.application"))">
                <img src="@(Url.Content("~/Images/LIJayCow-135.png"))" alt="Download Timer App" />
            </a>

            <div class="caption">
                <p>Run the Timer App on your computer to keep track of your time.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@(Url.Content("~/ProjectTimer/LITL.DesktopTimer.application"))">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>&nbsp;Download
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" style="height:300px; background: #f0e68c">

        <div class="thumbnail" style="width:100%; height:300px">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-primary" style="display: block; width: 100%; height:100%; font-size:large" href="@(Url.Content("~/ProjectTimer/LITL.DesktopTimer.application"))">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"> LIRA</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is change the div with the class "row" to the height you want.

```html
<div class="row" style="height:300px;">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="height:100%">
        <div class="thumbnail"  style="width:100%; height:100%">
            <a href="@(Url.Content("~/ProjectTimer/LITL.DesktopTimer.application"))">
                <img src="@(Url.Content("~/Images/LIJayCow-135.png"))" alt="Download Timer App" />
            </a>

            <div class="caption">
                <p>Run the Timer App on your computer to keep track of your time.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@(Url.Content("~/ProjectTimer/LITL.DesktopTimer.application"))">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>&nbsp;Download
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" style=" background: #f0e68c;height:100%">

        <div class="thumbnail" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" style="" href="@(Url.Content('~/ProjectTimer/LITL.DesktopTimer.application'))">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"> LIRA</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a result like this?

Codepen: [link](http://codepen.io/msaeli/pen/QNvbYL)

```
 <div class="row" style="height:300px;">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="@(Url.Content("~/ProjectTimer/LITL.DesktopTimer.application"))" >
            </a>
            <div class="caption" style="height:300px;">
                <p>Run the Timer App on your computer to keep track of your time.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@(Url.Content("~/ProjectTimer/LITL.DesktopTimer.application"))">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>&nbsp;Download
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" style="height:300px; background: #f0e68c">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="width:100%; height:300px">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-primary" style="display: block; width: 100%; height:100%; font-size:large" href="@(Url.Content("~/ProjectTimer/LITL.DesktopTimer.application"))">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share" style="font-size: 300px;">LIRA</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice that I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `btn-block` class, like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-block" >Show Details</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the button is 100% height when using h-100, the solution is to set the form element to 100% also.

So it'll look like this:

```html
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "h-100" }) {
  <button class="h-100">Button</button> 
}
```